# Ошибка при реализации метода загрузки файла на ftp сервер, java

Tags: java, android, ftp

Есть метод, который загружает файл на ftp-сервер, по нажатию кнопки.При отладке проекта на устройстве, по нажатию кнопки(запуску метода) происходить ошибка в приложении и оно вылетает.

Я использую следующий метод:

```
public static void FTPDownloadto() {
    String server = "192.168.0.103";
    int port = 21;
    String user = "anonymous";
    String pass = "";

    FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
    try {

        ftpClient.connect(server, port);
        ftpClient.login(user, pass);
        ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

        ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);


        // APPROACH #1: uploads first file using an InputStream
        File firstLocalFile = new File("\\storage\\ext_sd\\DCIM\\100MEDIA\\IMAG0171.jpg");

        String firstRemoteFile = "IMAG0171.jpg";
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(firstLocalFile);

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Начало загрузки первого файла", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        boolean done = ftpClient.storeFile(firstRemoteFile, inputStream);
        inputStream.close();
        if (done) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Первый фаил загружен успешно", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    inputStream.close();

    boolean completed = ftpClient.completePendingCommand();
    if (completed) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Ошибка:" + ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
    try {
    if (ftpClient.isConnected()) {
    ftpClient.logout();
    ftpClient.disconnect();
    }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

При запуске метода появляется ошибка:

```
android.os.NetworkOnMain.ThreadExseotion
```

Погуглив нашёл способ устранения этой ошибки, с помощью AsyncTask, но это тоже не устранило данную проблему. 
Используются библиотеки apache commons net, в манифесте android studio прописаны разрешения:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Непонятны способы устранения данной ошибки.

**Попытка решения проблемы с помощью AsyncTask:**

```
 class FTPUploadFile extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
//прежде чем задача выполнена
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Начало процесса", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

//после окончания задачи
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Процесс окончен", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {

}

//задача\
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    String server = "192.168.0.103";
    int port = 21;
    String user = "anonymous";
    String pass = "";

    FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
    try {

        ftpClient.connect(server, port);
        ftpClient.login(user, pass);
        ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

        ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);


        // APPROACH #1: uploads first file using an InputStream
        File firstLocalFile = new File("\\storage\\ext_sd\\DCIM\\100MEDIA\\IMAG0171.jpg");

        String firstRemoteFile = "IMAG0171.jpg";
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(firstLocalFile);

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Начало загрузки первого файла", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        boolean done = ftpClient.storeFile(firstRemoteFile, inputStream);
        inputStream.close();
        if (done) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Первый фаил загружен успешно", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        inputStream.close();

        boolean completed = ftpClient.completePendingCommand();
        if (completed) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Ошибка:" + ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (ftpClient.isConnected()) {
                ftpClient.logout();
                ftpClient.disconnect();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: AsyncTask должен был решит проблему. Видимо, вы не так его использовали. Покажите как.

Comment: Да я про тоже, но не вышло, я добавил код, посмотри

Comment: а вызов, который прописывал в кнопке: FTPUploadFile.execute();

Comment: Скорее всего у вас на Toast падало, т.к. его нельзя из неосновного потока вызывать. Попробуйте их убрать

Answer (score 2):

1. `doInBackground` не имеет доступа к графическому потоку, так что `Toast.makeText()` здесь лишний.
2. `AsynсTask` нужно запускать через метод `execute`, а не через вызов  `doInBackground`.